# how to using charAt()?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to distinguish the values entered by the user.

Users use an input form to add values.

If '#' is the front of the value entered by the user.
redirect to A

other than that
redirect to B

I tried to distinguish this by using charAt()
but do not work

I'm the first time using javascript, so there are many mistakes.
Can you take a look at my code?

html/javascript

```
<form>
    <input id="pathID" placeholder="Search ..." style="height:40px; line-height:40px; padding:0 15px;"> 
    <input onclick="return findSharp()" type="submit" value="Search" style="background:#222;">
</form>

<script>
    function findSharp() {
        var stringName = document.getElementById("pathID").value;

        if (stringName.charAt(0) == '#') {
            findURLA();
        } else {
            fidneURLB();
        }
    }

    function findURLA() {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/activity-2/' + '?' + 'hashtag/' + document.getElementById("pathID").value;

        return false;
    }

    function findURLB(){
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/mainpage/' + '?' + 'activity/' + document.getElementById("pathID").value;

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have a typo. The function is named as findURLB and called as fidneURLB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is true but you are using type="submit". So if you change this to button. You can do it.

Also, you typed your function name wrong. Change that to findURLB

```html
<form> <input id="pathID" placeholder="Search ..." style="height:40px; line-height:40px; padding:0 15px;"> 

<input onclick="return findSharp()" type="button" value="Search" style="background:#222;"></form>

<script>
function findSharp(){
var stringName = document.getElementById("pathID").value;
 if(stringName.charAt(0) == '#')
 {
  findURLA()
 }
 else
 {
  findURLB()
 }
}

function findURLA(){
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/activity-2/' + '?' + 'hashtag/' + document.getElementById("pathID").value;
return false;
}

function findURLB(){
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/mainpage/' + '?' + 'activity/' + document.getElementById("pathID").value;
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Really Thank you Thank you so much !!

Comment: @Kimchiman if you find this answer solves your question, then accept the answer by clicking the tick box which is left to this answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to validate your URL

```js
function isValidUrl(Url){
    if(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(Url))
        alert("URL is Valid");
    else
        alert("URL is Invalid");
}
```

```html
URL:  <input id="Url" onchange="isValidUrl(this.value)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Input type as **butt**on, Not **submit**

Pass argument directly to function if you want to redirect

```html
<form> <input id="pathID" placeholder="Search ..." style="height:40px; line-height:40px; padding:0 15px;"> 

<input onclick="return findSharp()" type="button" value="Search" style="background:#222;color:white;padding:10px"></form>

<script>
function findSharp(){
var stringName = document.getElementById("pathID").value;
if(stringName.charAt(0) == '#'){
 findURLA(stringName)
 }else{
  findURLB(stringName)
 }
}

function findURLA(data){
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/activity-2/' + '?' + 'hashtag/' + data;
return false;
}

function findURLB(data){
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8181/mainpage/' + '?' + 'activity/' + data;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the incorrect function name "fidneURLB".

If you correct it as "findURLB" the code should work.

Check the below code with comment which highlights the place of incorrect function call.

```js
<script>
function findSharp(){
var stringName = document.getElementById("pathID").value;
if(stringName.charAt(0) == '#'){
 findURLA()
 }
else{
//The function name was incorrect earlier :"fidneURLB"
 findURLB()
 }
}

function findURLA(){
document.write("I AM URL A");
return false;
}

function findURLB(){
document.write("I AM URL B");
return false;
}
</script>
```

```html
<form> 
    
    <input id="pathID" placeholder="Search ..." style="height:40px; line-height:40px; padding:0 15px;"> 

    <input onclick="return findSharp()" type="submit" value="Search">

</form>
```